# Orthogonal complement in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a line with parametric equations:
$x=2t, y=-5t, z=4t$ with $-\infty < t < \infty$, find the set of $W^\perp$ which is the orthogonal complement of $W$!

So far, I have only learned to find orthogonal complement from conventional equation, not the parametric ones. Can you help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ which are orthogonal to the vector $(2,-5,4)$ (a generator of $W$). Then
$$W^\perp=\{tu+sv\;:\;s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
For example you can take $u=(2,0,-1)$ and $v=(5,2,0)$. Can you find another couple?

Answer (score 0):

if the subspace is generated by the vector $n=(a,b,c)$,  then any $r=(x,y,z)$ in the orthogonal complement must satisfy $r \cdot n=0$, i.e.
$$
ax+by+cz = 0
$$